# need help about SQLite

Tags: c, sqlite, odbc

I want to add SQLite to an existing database application using odbc api. I'm very new to SQLite. so I need a few hints to startup. here is part of my code

```
wchar_t wszInStr[256] = L"DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver; Version=3; Database=D:\\Amin88\\AminDB.db; LongNames=0; Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL; StepAPI=0;"
wchar_t wszOutStr[1024];
SQLSMALLINT uOutLen = 0;    
retcode = SQLDriverConnectW(m_hdbc, hWndMain, wszInStr, _countof(wszInStr), wszOutStr, _countof(wszOutStr), &uOutLen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
const wchar_t * wszQuery = L"CREATE TABLE ATDBROLE ( \"ID\" INTEGER NOT NULL )" ;
SQLRETURN retcode;
retcode = ::SQLExecDirectW(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)wszQuery, SQL_NTS);
wprintf(L"retcode=%d\n", retcode); //retcode=100
```

SQLDriverConnectW returns 0(success), and file 'D:\Amin88\AminDB.db' is created with zero size? Does it mean that the database is created? why size is 0?
Assuming database created, Why CREATE DATABASE returns SQL_NODATA?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQlite3 ODBC manager creates the database with size 0 because SQLite format is a more general file format than database and It's size is 0 when it contains no objects. SQLExecuteDirectW returns SQL_NODATA because It expects ';' at the end of query, and The file size is nonzero only after commit transaction.